# How to only load and play the audio from a webpage embedded media file?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, media

The media file could could be HTML5, it could be Flash. Let's ignore other formats.

For HTML5 I imagine it's not too hard, by finding and interacting with the media object and its properties with Javascript, as the page is loading.

But for Flash, I think it's a different issue. Probably an external library necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check this, this site contains some info that might be useful

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp